# Dom does is not updated while testing redirection with react-testing library and react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test the redirection page when the user clicks on the button (I don't want to user `jest.mock()`).
I created the wrapper according to `test-react-library` documentation:

```
import { FC, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import { render, RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

const WrapperProviders: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>;
};

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  { route = "/" } = {},
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "wrapper">
) => {
  window.history.pushState({}, "Home Page", route);
  return {
    user: userEvent.setup(),
    ...render(ui, { wrapper: WrapperProviders, ...options })
  };
};

export * from "@testing-library/react";
export { customRender as render };
export type RenderType = ReturnType<typeof customRender>;
```

HomePage.tsx:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => navigate("/other");
  return (
    <>
      <h3>HomePage</h3>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Redirect</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Other.tsx:

```
export default function Other() {
  return <h3>Other</h3>;
}
```

HomePage.test.tsx:

```
import { render, RenderType } from "./customRender";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

describe("HomePage", () => {
  let wrapper: RenderType;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(<HomePage />, { route: "/" });
  });

  test.only("Should redirects to other page", async () => {
    const { getByText, user } = wrapper;

    expect(getByText(/homepage/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    const button = getByText(/redirect/i);
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    user.click(button);
    expect(getByText(/other/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

When I run the test, it fails and the page is not updated in the dom.
Does jest-dom does not support the re-render of the page and update the DOM? Or this test out of scope of the testing-library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the custom render and add a history for it:

```
const WrapperProviders: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>;
};

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  { route = "/",
    history = createMemoryHistory({initialEntries: [route]}),
   } = {},
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "wrapper">
) => {
  return {
    user: userEvent.setup(),
    ...render( <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
         ui
        </Router>
     , { wrapper: WrapperProviders, ...options })

  };
};
```

and the test now passes:

```
describe("HomePage", () => {
  let wrapper: RenderType;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(<HomePage />, { route: "/" });
  });

  test.only("Should redirects to other page", async () => {
    const { getByText, user, history } = wrapper;

    expect(getByText(/homepage/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    const button = getByText(/redirect/i);
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    await user.click(button);
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/other');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code I can see that you are just rendering the **HomePage** component and inside of that component you don't have any logic that renders a new component based on the route changes (I suppose that you have that logic on another component). That's why when you click on the button you are not seeing the **Other** component rendered.

In this case I would suggest you to only make the assertions you need on the *window.location* object. So after you simulate the click on the button you can do:

```
expect(window.location.pathname).toBe("/other");
```